# Boolean circuit size of $i$th bit of determinant?

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits

Berkowitz algorithm provides a polynomial size circuit with logarithmic depth for determinant of a square matrix using matrix powers.

Is there a polynomial size boolean circuit for $i$th bit of determinant and is it still logarithmic depth?

Comment: Can you provide some references to your question?

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17501/cancellation-and-determinant.